# Pauli-Lubanski square operator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, poincare-symmetry

The Pauli-Lubanski operator is given by:

$$ W_\mu = -\frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} J^{\nu \rho}P^{\sigma}$$

Thus the square operator is given by:

$$ W_\mu W^\mu = W^2 = -\frac{1}{4} \epsilon_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}\epsilon^{\mu \alpha \beta \gamma} J^{\nu \rho} J_{\alpha \beta} P^{\sigma} P_{\gamma}$$

knowing that $\epsilon_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}\epsilon^{\mu \alpha \beta \gamma} = 3!\delta^{\alpha \beta \gamma}_{[\nu \rho \sigma]}$, I get the following expression:

$$ W^2 = \frac{1}{2} J^{\nu \rho} J_{\nu \rho} P^{2} -J^{\nu \rho} J_{\nu \sigma} P^{\sigma} P_{\rho}  $$

but, how do I act with operator on a spin state?

How do I prove that
$$W^2 |m,\vec{p} = 0, s, s_z \rangle = -m^2 S^2 = - m^2s(s+1) ~?$$

Comment: Did you try $J = L + S$ for each term and develop the expression? It is a lot of terms, but at the end of the day you should get $w^2 = S(S+1)P_{\mu} P^{\mu}$

Comment: I found an easier way in Ashok Das's book,  I'll post it when I can! Thank you for trying to help!